# jquery mousewheel zoom (changing width of div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zooming

I would like to be able to change the width of my div using the mousewheel.
I guess this is very hard to do (at least to hard for me), but I thought maybe someone has ever written such a jquery or javascript code.

To put in some context: here is the relevant part of my website: http://jsfiddle.net/XGERP/1/
And here is the complete [website](http://euclidthegame.com/books/LA2/H3/Sectie%203.0/1.php).  I would like the user to decide how big the  `#main div` is going to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some jquery to tickle your fancy. Tested to work in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').bind('wheel mousewheel', function(e){
        var delta;

        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta !== undefined)
            delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        else
            delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY * -1;

            if(delta > 0) {
                $("#main").css("width", "+=10");
            }
            else{
                $("#main").css("width", "-=10");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Nice work @ryanpf, better than my shitty suggestion, of downloading an extra plugin etc.... :)

Comment: Does not work on Firefox, at least not with the Fiddle. Did work on Chrome.

Comment: @user2261892 thank you for testing. Downloaded FF just to test and can't get it to work with FF's supposed substitute, DOMMouseScroll.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jquery Zoom...

http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Then just as the user hovers, they can read a bit closer...

Not sure if it would work with text though, haven't really looked into it

Or you could do something like this...

```
 $('#main').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
var delta_px = delta > 0 ? "+=50" : "-=50";
$(this).css('width', delta_px);
});
```

You need the `mousewheel` extension plugin for that...

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel

Heres a working demo, the mousewheel script is above everything, then the actual jquery you want is at the bottom

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/scpDH/81/)